# Choose a JavaScript framework/s after mastering the basics

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I'm trying to learn JavaScript, but seem to be going around in circles regarding primitives, objects, functions, etc. I can code fairly well in Python, so the JavaScript part is now mostly about syntax and idioms.

I am overwhelmed by the choices and I'm not sure how to choose: Prototype, jQuery, Dojo, Node.js, Backbone.js, etc.

What would be good JavaScript framework/s to pick up after mastering the basics? At the risk of betraying my JavaScript naivete, I'd like one (or a combination of) framework wherein I can do asynchronous requests, data visualization, and UI implementation.

Comment: This question is subjective...

Comment: Regarding the things you mention in your last sentence (async requests, etc.), I'd recommend doing them in "plain" JavaScript at least once so that you know how things work. You'll see immediately that as with event handling you have to write different cases to cater for the differences between browsers. _Then_ switch to a library and let it handle the nuisance stuff for you - I use and recommend jQuery (but have nothing against the other libraries).

Comment: @nnnnnn You don't need a framework/library that provides an abstracted API to do browser compliance. You can use one of the many polyfills/shims that do browser support and still do it in "plain" javascript.

Comment: @Raynos - Sure; I don't disagree. But a lot of people _do_ switch to using a library for that stuff, and I was trying to say that before doing so it is best to understand the background stuff that the library is hiding from you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which JavaScript framework (jQuery vs Dojo vs ... )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't be right to not first say to make sure you understand JavaScript itself first. It's a rather unique language with both good parts and bad parts. If you take the time to understand closure, prototypal inheritance, `this` keyword, constructor functions, etc, you will thank yourself. [JavaScript, The Good Parts](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742) is an excellent place to start. Anyways...

For basic DOM manipulation, event handling, ajax, etc [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is the clear winner. In the past, [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/)/[Scriptaculous](http://script.aculo.us/) was a common alternative.

For more advanced browser-based applications, [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/), [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/), and [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) are the winners.

[Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/), [Mootools](http://mootools.net/), [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs), and [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) are some alternatives to Angular and friends... all with varying strengths and focuses.

There are countless libraries for charting. [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is a popular one. For more advanced visualizations, check out [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) and [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

[Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) is different beast. It's a server-side, network IO platform. It's competitors are things like Python's Twisted and Ruby's EventMachine.

Of course this topic has been covered in great length here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs

Answer (score 2):

> I can do asynchronous requests, data visualization, and UI implementation.

- async requests means [XHR2](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest2/)
- data visualization and UI means HTML, [DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/) or [`<canvas>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element)

If you want to *learn* and really *learn* stick with the low level basics and don't use bloated abstractions.

Sure when you use jQuery you might finish it faster, but you won't learn anything other then how to hack together spaghetti code using jQuery. Your code wouldn't be anywhere near as maintainable, stable or performant if you had just learned how to do it right with plain old javascript.

Comment: _"UI means DOM4 or `<canvas>`"_ - no it doesn't. The UI is _anything_ the user interacts with, which could just be some plain text and a few hyperlinks. "User Interface" doesn't imply graphics. (Not that I'm saying one shouldn't learn about DOM4 or `<canvas>`.)

Comment: +1 but... `Sure using jQuery is faster` where "faster" means? jQuery is often used by those who haven't bothered to learn javascript or browser scripting, so in that sense it might be faster to get a particular result. But overall things like compatability, quality, maintainability and performance are at best the same as a sound POJS approach and often worse. No library can fix bad design or shoddy programming.

Comment: @nnnnnn Good point I just assumed he would want something more then just HTML or otherwise he wouldn't ask for a js library.

Comment: @RobG I meant it's faster to hack something together. I already hinted at the fact that quality, maintainability & performance are not as good as using the APIs directly.

Answer (score 0):

For the first steps I'll recommend [jQuery](http://jquery.com), with it's intuitive syntax and ability to be extended with bunch of plugins, and for it's strong community and huge amount of articles, tutorials, etc. on [the internet](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery).

> jQuery is a cross-browser JavaScript library that provides
>   abstractions for DOM traversal, event handling, animation, and AJAX

Try it at first, then you can go with other frameworks based on the task requirements like [Raphaël JS](http://raphaeljs.com) for vector graphics,[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) for animations, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 3 main/major frameworks to consider. The reason I choose the following 3 is because they are fairly well supported, document and used, but more importantly - they all suggest a different coding style/convention.

1. [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/)
2. [ExtJS (Sencha)](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)
3. [jQuery (UI/core)](http://jquery.com/)

Should be noted that any one of them can be fit to almost any coding style/preference, but if I were to create the perfect (from working with it standpoint) framework, I would do a hybrid:

Dojo's widget creation and styling + ExtJS layouting capabilities and stores-based data managemenet + jQuery DOM manipulation and AJAX support.